# How can I change the default Terminal app?

Tags: applications, keyboard-shortcuts, pantheon-terminal

I would like to replace the default Terminal with the `gnome-terminal`. Is this possible?

If I install `gnome-terminal` via `apt-get` it does not show up in the applications menu and I can't find an option to replace the <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> keyboard shortcut to open `gnome-terminal` instead of `pantheon-terminal`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can set the default terminal by changing the alternative for `x-terminal-emulator`. Installing **gnome-terminal** creates an alternative symlink so all you have to do is set it.

```
sudo update-alternatives --set x-terminal-emulator /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper
```

**Edit:** It seems like the shortcut implementation is not using the alternative, but rather a *gsettings* configuration. It's still a good idea to set the alternative symlink above, however, to use the keyboard shortcut some gsettings properties will need to be modified. Use *dconf-editor* (`sudo apt-get install dconf-editor`) or *gsettings* to change the default terminal application to **gnome-terminal**. You will need to modify the *exec* and *exec-arg* properties in the *org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal* schema.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec gnome-terminal
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec-arg ''
```

Comment: in dconf Editor go to  org > gnome > desktop > applications > terminal (which corresponds to org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal schema as in the answer ) change value of exec to executable of your app st (simple suckless terminal) xterm(xterm) etc