# Unable to launch gnome-terminal from app launcher

Tags: pantheon-terminal, slingshot

I have installed multiple terminals. I was able to launch all the terminals from app launcher except `gnome-terminal`.

*What I have tried so far*:

- I followed the link: [How can I change the default Terminal app?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1344/how-can-i-change-the-default-terminal-app)

  It changed default terminal to `gnome-terminal` (I verified in `dconf-tools`) but still I don't find `gnome-terminal` in app launcher.
- I have binded shortcut key to open `gnome-terminal`. It's working.
- I also tried the command `sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator` to select available terminals.
- Also there is no option to keep in dock.

*My question*:

How to launch `gnome-terminal` from app launcher and how to lock it to dock?

Comment: It is dup but not exact dup o_O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you question is similar to this one:
[Why don't certain GNOME apps show in Slingshot?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/2994/2461)

Have a look in the file in `/usr/share/applications/gnome-terminal.desktop`. It must have a **OnlyShowIn** entry. Remove it or add **Pantheon** there.

Comment: I remember last time I tried same, but this time worked. o_O