# How to install ccleaner in elementary OS

Tags: software-installation

In Windows , I used to use CCleaner. How to install ccleaner in elementary OS?

I am new to linux so I don't want to use terminal methods(CLI) to clean the system. I would prefer GUI tool/method.

Comment: @PNG I don't think its a duplicate :)

Comment: I agree with PNG that it is a duplicate. The purpose of an app like CCleaner would be to perform these types of tasks. If you'd like to suggest bleachbit, I think it should happen on this other question.

Comment: @DanielForé it is very rude to downvote a question, if you feel it is duplicate

Comment: The tooltip of the downvote button has criteria one of which is "This question does not show any research effort". This is a pretty clear duplicate question and no offense but it seems like you're just trying to farm reputation here

Comment: Well @DanielForé, what do you say about your [comment](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3568/how-to-install-ccleaner-in-elementary-os#comment6220_3568) ? I said " I am leaving this to community" there is nothing wrong. If I feel duplicate, I close it immediately  http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3031/unable-to-launch-gnome-terminal-from-app-launcher

Comment: @Ravan it is not rude to downvote a question, especially one that is clearly an unnecessary duplicate.